# how to count number of rows in a data range?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have some data for example in the following format
Score data range is from 1 to 100
Following is data from table "ProductScore" for example 
attaching a pic and result required format

[image: Tables]

I am a bit new to SQL 
I think it's simple to write query.

Comment: In this case it doesn't make much difference, but typically selectable text is preferable to images, so I'd rollback your last edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `CASE`:

```
;with cte AS (SELECT CASE WHEN Score <= 10 THEN '01: 1-10'
                          WHEN Score <= 20 THEN '02: 11-20'
                          ....
                          ELSE '10: 91-100'
                     END AS Ranges
                    ,ProductCode
              FROM ProductScore
             )
SELECT Ranges,COUNT(ProductCode)
FROM cte
GROUP BY Ranges
ORDER BY Ranges
```

Note: I include a prefix to the ranges so that it can be ordered by the ranges, you can adjust to suit.

I put this in a cte so that I don't have to list the `CASE` again in the `GROUP BY`, as AlexPoole suggest, you could add another `CASE` for ordering and eliminate the prefix:

```
;with cte AS (SELECT CASE WHEN Score <= 10 THEN '1-10'
                          WHEN Score <= 20 THEN '11-20'
                          ....
                          ELSE '91-100'
                     END AS Ranges
                     CASE WHEN Score <= 10 THEN 1
                          WHEN Score <= 20 THEN 2
                          ....
                          ELSE 10
                     END AS RangeOrder
                    ,ProductCode
              FROM ProductScore
             )
SELECT Ranges,COUNT(ProductCode)
FROM cte
GROUP BY Ranges
ORDER BY RangeOrder
```

Comment: The alias name shouldn't be quoted. Personally I'd maybe repeat the `case` to give a second pseudocolumn to order by, rather than having a prefix; but that has maintenance implictions, and I guess is a matter of opinion *8-)

Comment: @AlexPoole good catch, updated.  Oh, I see what you were saying about repeating the case, that's a good idea, will add that too.

Answer (score 2):

As your interval are fixed width, you can use the Oracle's nice function [`WIDTH_BUCKET`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions214.htm) to achieve the desired result:

```
SELECT (wb-1)*10+1 || '-' || wb*10 "DataRange" , COUNT(*) FROM ( 

  SELECT WIDTH_BUCKET("Score",1,100,10) wb
  --     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  --    divide the [1..100] range in 10 buckets of the
  --    same size
  FROM ProductScore

) V
GROUP BY wb
ORDER BY wb
```

See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/91e85/6 for a live example

---

In addition, if you need to display even the buckets without any data, you might want to add an outer join and change the `COUNT` function:

```
SELECT (wb-1)*10+1 || '-' || wb*10 "DataRange" , COUNT("Score") FROM ( 
--                                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
--                                       Count only row having a score
--                                       Can't use COUNT(*) here because
--                                       of the full outer join below

  SELECT WIDTH_BUCKET("Score",1,100,10) wb, "Score"
  FROM ProductScore

) V1

FULL OUTER JOIN (SELECT LEVEL wb FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 10) V2
USING(wb)
-- ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
-- always 10 buckets (from 1-10 to 91-100)


GROUP BY wb
ORDER BY wb;
```

Take a look at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/91e85/9 to see the difference.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want ranges of 10 you can divide `score` by 10 and group by the rounded down value

```
select to_char(floor("Score"/10)*10+1) || '-' || to_char(floor("Score"/10)*10+10),
count(*) 
from Table1
group by floor("Score"/10)
order by floor("Score"/10)
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/df1088/8